# star rating html, css

Tags: html, css

I did stuck here and need help. How can I use a tag for for each button? Can somebody help me to finish this star rating code?
"For each button use only a single a tag, with as many span tags as you need."
All help will be appreciated, thanks.

here is my code:

```css
 h2 {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 20px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: Calibri;

    }

    #box {
        outline: 10px double;
        outline-color: black;
        outline-offset: 1px;
        background: steelblue;
        width: 450px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 45px;
        text-align: right;
        display: inline-block;

    }

    .star-icon {
        color: ghostwhite;
        font-size: 2em;
        position: relative;
    }

    .star-icon.full:before {
        color: yellow;
        content: '\2605';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="box">
<h2>Rating</h2>
<div class="position">
    <span class="star-icon full">☆</span>
    <span class="star-icon full">☆</span>
    <span class="star-icon ">☆</span>
    <span class="star-icon ">☆</span>
    <span class="star-icon">☆</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is a "tag" here referring to css-classes? Is a button a star? Vocabulary and specificity matters. Do you want `star-icon-full` instead of `star-icon full`?

Comment: Thanks for answer @ippi Yes, button should be a star. `star-icon-full` sounds good.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to figure out the end goal here.

Comment: I understand,:)

Comment: "For each button need use only a single a tag, with as many span tags as I need" —  This is a terrible requirement. That is completely the wrong HTML to describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That is why this making me confuse @Quentin. I got to chance to do my internship and the company want me to do those tests. Only this one left, I did stuck.

Comment: @ippi The a tag is the button. I am supposed to use CSS to style it to look like a button. The text and stars are children of the a tag, each wrapped in a span. Did I understand right?

Answer (score 2):

Html code:

```
<fieldset class="rating">
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
<input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
```

css file :

```
    @import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }
.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}
.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}
.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}
.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}
.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */
.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

Kindly check this code might be helpful

Comment: Yes this code might be helpful but the rule is for my code; "For each button use only a single <a> tag, with as many <span> tags as you need."

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out a much cleaner solution for CSS only star ratings. I am covering a form input field as well as a simple showcase element. I've also written [a blog post with more details](https://blog.nicohood.de/pure-css-only-html-star-rating-no-javascript) and a [codepen](https://codepen.io/nicohood/pen/dyWzvJN).

```
// Colors
$star-color: #FFC600;

// Star definitions
%full-star {
  &:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f005";
  }
};

%half-star {
  &:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f123";
  }
};

%empty-star {
  &:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f006";
  }
};

// 5 Star Rating Showcase
.rating-score {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: $star-color;

  .rating-score-item {
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;

    @extend %empty-star;
  }

  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    &[data-rating='#{$i}'] {
      .rating-score-item:nth-child(-n + #{$i}) {
        @extend %full-star;
      }
    }
  }
  
  @for $i from 0 through 4 {
    &[data-rating='#{$i + 0.5}'] {
      .rating-score-item:nth-child(-n + #{$i}) {
        @extend %full-star;
      }

      .rating-score-item:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
        @extend %half-star;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="rating-score" data-rating="4">
  <li class="rating-score-item"></li>
  <li class="rating-score-item"></li>
  <li class="rating-score-item"></li>
  <li class="rating-score-item"></li>
  <li class="rating-score-item"></li>
</ul>
```